# Flutter filter data from rest api using Future Builder

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I am trying to filter out the results of the data from a REST api but do not seem to have an understanding of how to go about it. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that I want to have a single class that gets all my events data from the api and using different classes, be able to retrieve specific data by filtering the data from the original events class.

Below is my code:

```
late Future<List<EntertainerEvent>> _fetchEvents;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchEvents = _authAPI.fetchEvents();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<EntertainerEvent>>(
        future: _fetchEvents,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          var childCount = 0;
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            childCount = 1;
          } else {
            childCount = snapshot.data.length;
          }
          return SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<EntertainerEvent> someData = snapshot.data;
                  return InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 380.0,
                      color: const Color(0xFF00001A),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color(0xFF0492C2),
                              blurRadius: 10,
                              offset: Offset(0, 0),
                            ),
                          ],
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: 210,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0.0),
                                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0.0)),
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    image: new NetworkImage(
                                        _authAPI.mediaPath +
                                            someData[index].imagePoster)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: 120,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 10.0, bottom: 0.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  someData[index]
                                                      .eventName
                                                      .toUpperCase(),
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                                                  ),
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  softWrap: true,
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    top: 6.0, bottom: 0.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  someData[index].eventTypeId ==
                                                          3
                                                      ? 'Online Location'
                                                      : someData[index].suburb +
                                                          ', ' +
                                                          someData[index].city +
                                                          ', ' +
                                                          someData[index]
                                                              .province,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black26,
                                                  ),
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  softWrap: true,
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Container(
                                                padding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      _startDate(
                                                              someData[index])
                                                          .toString()
                                                          .toUpperCase(),
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.red,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                        fontSize: 10,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    FavouriteWidget(
                                                        entEvent:
                                                            someData[index]),
                                                    IconButton(
                                                      icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        Share.share(//Do Something);
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return EventDetails(
                            entEvent: someData[index],
                            isFavourited: _isFavourited);
                      }));
                    },
                  );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    'An Error Occured!',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  content: Text(
                    "${snapshot.error}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Go Back',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.3,
                    child: Center(
                      child:
                          CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xFFFFA500)),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }, childCount: childCount),
          );
        });
```

Bare in mind that in my HomePage(), I am calling this class using the code below:

```
return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF00001A),
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Builder(
          // This Builder is needed to provide a BuildContext that is
          // "inside" the NestedScrollView, so that
          // sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor() can find the
          // NestedScrollView.
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CustomScrollView(
              // The "controller" and "primary" members should be left
              // unset, so that the NestedScrollView can control this
              // inner scroll view.
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverOverlapInjector(
                  // This is the flip side of the SliverOverlapAbsorber
                  // above.
                  handle:
                      NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                ),
                EventList(),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding you right just do this for example:

```
if(someData[index].eventTypeId == '1'){
  return SizedBox();
    }
    else{
     return InkWell( ....
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, so your response will only work within the base class but like I said, I am trying to use the data on the base class by filtering it on the child classes, the filtering has to happen outside of the first block of code above.